# Changing the form component ID used in Wicket's feedback messages

Tags: java, validation, wicket

I have some forms on my page with a feedback panel. the formcomponents have different validators. I'd like to keep the feedbackmessages of the validators that come with Wicket so I dont have to write my own properties for every formcomponent and validator I might use.

My problem is that these messages name the field which has thrown the error by their internal component ID, which is pretty impractical :/

Like I said, I want to keep the original localized error messages for most validators but implement the localized components naming myself. I tried setting some attributes to the input tags, hoping wicket will look for some of them and also tried to set the markupId but this doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give each FormComponent a label for its messages, see FormComponent#setLabel(IModel).